# How to get number of distinct column entries by user in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database of user activities. For a specific user, I want to return the number of distinct types of activities they did. For example:

Bob:
 Activity 1: type A
 Activity 2: Type B
 Activity 3: Type A

The result should be 2 because of two distinct activities (A and B).

I tried the following command:

```
Activity.activity_type.query.filter(Activity.user_id==1).distinct(Activity.activity_type)
```

The `Activity.activity_type` part is giving an error. I look on StackOverflow and documentation, but could not find how to properly use `distinct` in this situation. I would appreciate help on how to get this query to work.

Comment: Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: could you also post your models ?

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse my original interpretation of your objective, it was not correct as returned a count of each activity attempted, not a count of distinct activities attempted.

See below for a solution to the problem which was supplied by Ilja Everilä in the comments.

However, the exception that you are getting occurs before your query is executed (I think, as I've reverse engineered your models from the query that you've provided) so the bulk of this answer is focused on that:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor
>   'Comparator' object associated with Activity.activity_type has an
>   attribute 'query'

I created these models in order to execute your query:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(16))

class Activity(db.Model):
    activity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    activity_type = db.Column(db.String(32))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User')
```

Then wrote a little script to add some data:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        names = ['batman', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'names']
        users = [User(name=name) for name in names]
        db.session.add_all(users)
        activities = [
            'Self Doubt',
            'Dark Introspection',
            'Gotham Needs Me',
            'Training Montage',
            'Fight Crime',
            'Get the girl'
        ]
        db.session.add_all(
            [Activity(
                activity_type=random.choice(activities),
                user=random.choice(users)
            ) for _ in range(20)]
        )

        db.session.commit()
```

Executing `Activity.activity_type.query.filter(Activity.user_id==1).distinct(Activity.activity_type)` raises the aforementioned error.

The problem comes from this part of your query `Activity.activity_type.query`. It's saying that it's looked for an attribute called `'query'` on `Activity.activity_type` but couldn't find it. Breaking the error message down a bit:

We know that `Activity.activity_type` is an instance of `Column` when we define it on the model, but `print(Activity.activity_type)` shows `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>`, so that's the first object referenced in the error. The `Comparitor` is an internal sqlalchemy construct that is also checked  (you can find it with `Activity.activity_type.comparator` if you're interested). So sqlalchemy looked for, and couldn't find, an attribute with the name `'query'` on the `Activity.activity_type` column.

The `.query` property comes from the `db.Model` base that your models inherit from and will only be available to objects in the same [MRO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/) as `db.Model`. Because the column objects don't inherit from `db.Model`, you cannot access the query property through them. `Activity.query` is legal, `Activity.activity_type.query` is not.

This is the query that Ilja provided in comment to my original answer which is the correct solution:

```py
        batman_activity_count = db.session.query(
            db.func.count(
                Activity.activity_type.distinct()
            )
        ).filter(Activity.user_id==1).scalar()

        print(batman_activity_count)  # random integer b/w 0 and 6.
```

Comment: Yeh I have got that wrong, thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit accordingly. I'm glad I chose to focus on explaining the exception, so there's something to salvage!